# Picking up values from several csv files in R

Tags: r

I have a folder where several csv files are dumped. File names can be Product_1234.csv Product_2121.csv etc

The column names in these sheets are different. However there is always one column "Profit" which is there in all sheets. Hence Product_1234.csv and Product_2121.csv will both have Profit as a column.

I have another csv i.e my_csv.csv file in which data is in the following format

```
Product Cost
1234    12
2345    10
2121    15
```

I want to have another column in my_csv named Profit. This column should have the Profit from the multiple sheets talked about earlier. For example, to get the Profit for Product 1234 we will have to search for filename which has "1234" and the pick up the Profit from that file. I am not sure if this can be done in R. Please help.

The output file i.e my_csv will be something like this

```
 Product Cost Profit 
 1234    12    3
 2121    15    1
```

Comment: Do you know the names of the products? Or do they need to be worked out from which files are present?

Comment: This is quite a broad question. This can be done in R. See `?ls`, `?read.csv`, and `?merge` for starters.

Comment: @JamesElderfield  I have the names of the products in my_csv file. I want to map the Profit against these products.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would do it

```
# Dummy data - read this in from your my_csv.csv file
my_csv_data = data.frame(
    Product = c(1234, 2121),
    Cost = c(12, 15)    
)

profits <- c()

for(productNumber in my_csv_data$Product) {
    fileName <- paste0("Product_", productNumber, ".csv")

    productData <- read.csv(fileName)

    profits <- c(profits, productData$Profit[1])
}

my_csv_data$Profit <- profits
```

There are certainly faster ways of doing this, but this gives you somewhere to start from if performance is an issue.